# Permanent shortcut keys for Apple Pages text styles

Tags: shortcut, pages

In Apple Pages, I hate having to set F1, F2, F3, etc for each level of style like Title, Body, Heading 1, etc every time I start a new document. Is there a way to do this permanently?

Comment: Use a basic template?

Comment: I guess that's the only way possible right now. It'd still be nice to have something configurable.